# How to create a Personal Geodatabase

Tags: arcobjects

How can I create an Access (.mdb) file containing a personal geodatabase?

Comment: Based on your other questions, it looks like you're developing apps with ArcEngine, but without ArcGIS desktop.  If you're just getting familiar with ArcGIS, I'd highly recommend getting  ArcView (at minimum).  Full disclosure - I'm a reseller.

Comment: Is the down vote for the user or for the question?  I think the question is useful for gis.stackexchange.com and is 100% aligned with the FAQ as it currently is written. Future gis.stackexchange.com answer seekers won't necessarily care about iterationx's line of questions.  Downvotes like this will probably scare potential users back to the ESRI forums.

Comment: the downvote, I surmise, is because creating a personal gdb for most is trivial in the extreme, analogous to asking "How do I create a new folder in Windows Explorer?" If as Kirk suggests he doesn't have ArcMap/Catalog that should be part of the question, e.g. "How to create a personal gdb through ArcGIS-Engine/ArcObjects/python/... and without Arcmap or Arccatalog?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Creating a Personal geodatabase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004t8000000).

Answer (score 3):

To build on  @jswise's answer and your comment, you can create either personal geodb or file geodb in ArcCatalog or ArcMap using the command-line window.  If the window isn't visible, you can go to **Window** menu and select the **Command Line** menu-item.

Of course, there are other ways to create them--this is just how I typically do it.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use Microsoft Access to create a database, or you could use ArcCatalog to create a personal geodatabase.  Both are MDBs.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed your tag.  Did you mean you want to create an MDB using ArcObjects?

Comment: I want to do some geocoding, and all these documents say to open up a workspace mdb or gdb, and I don't have either on my system, so I am trying to create one, I don't care how.